# Reduce the delay of touchpad disable while typing

Tags: touchpad

I set the setting to disable touchpad while typing. Is there a way to reduce the default delay to start using it again after stopping typing?

Answer (score 3):

Depending on your system, you could try

> syndaemon -i 4 -d

where -i is idle-time. You can configure that.